MemoryCache Eviction Callback Not Triggered Consistently
Hello StackOverflow community,
I'm working with the MemoryCache class in .NET and I've encountered some inconsistent behavior with eviction callbacks. Specifically, I've noticed that the eviction callback is only triggered when I include a check using TryGetValue after the cache item is expected to expire.
Here’s a simplified example of my code:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

var cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
{
    ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
});

cache.Set("test", "test", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
}
.RegisterPostEvictionCallback((key, value, reason, state) => 
    Console.WriteLine($"Cache item '{key}' was evicted because: {reason}")));

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for cache to expire...");
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Test Results:
When including TryGetValue:
In this version, I check the existence of the cache item after the expected expiration time has passed.
Console Output:
Waiting for cache to expire...
Cache item 'test' was evicted because: Expired
Finished waiting.

Here, the eviction callback is triggered, and the cache item is correctly shown as expired.
When removing TryGetValue:
If I remove the TryGetValue check, the code looks like this:
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

var cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions
{
    ExpirationScanFrequency = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)
});

cache.Set("test", "test", new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
{
    AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
}
.RegisterPostEvictionCallback((key, value, reason, state) => 
    Console.WriteLine($"Cache item '{key}' was evicted because: {reason}")));

Console.WriteLine("Waiting for cache to expire...");
await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));

Console.WriteLine("Finished waiting."); 

Console Output:
Waiting for cache to expire...
Finished waiting. 

In this case, the eviction callback does not seem to be triggered, and I only see the messages indicating the waiting period.
Questions:

Why does the eviction callback only seem to be triggered when
TryGetValue is used?
Is there an issue with how eviction is handled
in the MemoryCache class?
Could this behavior be due to timing or
buffering issues related to console output? Any insights or
suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Wrong mental model.  MemoryCache is lazy, there is no set of timers or worker thread, busily watching for expired items.  Nothing happens until you do something with the cache, like retrieving an item.  So you didn't get the callback because the item wasn't expired yet.
